# use S3 as MapReduce job input

Tags: amazon-s3, mapreduce

i have a MR job to read file on amazon S3 and process the data on local hdfs. the files are zipped text file as .gz. i tried to setup the job as below but it won't work, anyone know what might be wrong?  do i need to add extra step to unzip the file first?

thanks!

```
String S3_LOCATION = "s3n://access_key:private_key@bucket_name"

protected void prepareHadoopJob() throws Exception {    

    this.getHadoopJob().setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
    this.getHadoopJob().setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(this.getHadoopJob(), new Path(S3_LOCATION));

this.getHadoopJob().setNumReduceTasks(0);
this.getHadoopJob().setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);
this.getHadoopJob().getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, myTable.getTableName());
this.getHadoopJob().setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
this.getHadoopJob().setOutputValueClass(Put.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should not need to unzip the file first but it is tough to identify what went wrong without any details on the error message